# Asp.net single controller action with different model type depending on route data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I want to create a generic action in my controller. The model that I would read from the body depends on other route data.

For example I have a `resources` controller with a `create` action. the route is something like this `/api/[controller]/[action]/{resource}` where `resource` is a route parameter.

So, `POST: /api/resources/create/book` should create a book resource in the repository. Each resource has it's own `CreateModel`. For instace `book` may use

```
class BookCreateModel
{
   [Required]
   public string Title {get; set;}

   [Required]
   public Guid AuthorId {get; set;}

   ... // etc
}
```

I would like my action to have a signature like the one below

```
public Task<IActionResult> Create([FromRoute] resource, [FromBody] object model)
{
   if(!ModelState.IsValid)
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
   ...
}
```

The actual `model` type should depend on the `resource` parameter and the action name (`create` in this example)

I should probably create a model binder, but I want to have all the funtionality of the default model binder (ModelState, validations etc). The only **different** thing I want to do is to choose which model type it should bind to. The rest should be kept the same.

Is there a way to do it, or should I implement the whole binding logic myself?

Comment: Do you have a special use case that requires a design like this? Just asking as it seems rather counter-intuitive compared to a more standard resource based (or REST) API design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling, the only solution I could find and address my problem was to create my own binder that would mimic the default `BodyModelBinder`.

Then, in the place were the `InputFormatterContext` was instantiated, instead of passing `bindingContext.ModelMetadata` as the 4th argument, I pass `bindingContext.ModelMetadata.GetMetadataForType([desired type here])`, where the type I pass depends on other context values (such as route parameters, controller and action context etc).

Then I use the binder using a binder attribute in my action like this

```
[HttpPut("{resource}"), ActionName("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateResource(
   [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(BodyResourceModelBinder))] object model
)
{
   ...
}
```

By executing `.GetType()` in the model instance, I get the actual type I had set in the binder's code.

The final binder code is this:

```
public class BodyResourceModelBinder: IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IList<IInputFormatter> _formatters;
    private readonly Func<Stream, Encoding, TextReader> _readerFactory = (s, e) => new StreamReader(s, e);
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public BodyResourceModelBinder(IOptions<MvcOptions> mvcOptions, ILogger<BodyResourceModelBinder> logger = null)
    {
        if(mvcOptions == null || mvcOptions.Value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mvcOptions));
        _formatters = mvcOptions.Value.InputFormatters.ToList();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    internal bool AllowEmptyBody { get; set; }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if(bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }
        string modelBindingKey;
        if(bindingContext.IsTopLevelObject)
        {
            modelBindingKey = bindingContext.BinderModelName ?? string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            modelBindingKey = bindingContext.ModelName;
        }
        var httpContext = bindingContext.HttpContext;
        var formatterContext = new InputFormatterContext(
             httpContext,
             modelBindingKey,
             bindingContext.ModelState,

             // THIS IS THE ACTUAL CHANGE. I CREATE NEW METADATA BASED ON THE TYPE I WANT TO BIND TO
             bindingContext.ModelMetadata.GetMetadataForType(typeof(<PUT YOUR TYPE HERE>)),

             _readerFactory,
             AllowEmptyBody);

        var formatter = (IInputFormatter)null;
        for(var i = 0; i < _formatters.Count; i++)
        {
            if(_formatters[i].CanRead(formatterContext))
            {
                formatter = _formatters[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if(formatter == null)
        {
            var message = $"Unsupported content type: {httpContext.Request.ContentType}";
            var exception = new UnsupportedContentTypeException(message);
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelBindingKey, exception, bindingContext.ModelMetadata);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var result = await formatter.ReadAsync(formatterContext);

            if(result.HasError)
                return;

            if(result.IsModelSet)
            {
                // The actual type of result.Model here is the type you provided in the Metadata of the IInputFormatter above
                var model = result.Model;
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }
            else
            {
                var message = bindingContext
                     .ModelMetadata
                     .ModelBindingMessageProvider
                     .MissingRequestBodyRequiredValueAccessor();
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelBindingKey, message);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception) when(exception is InputFormatterException || ShouldHandleException(formatter))
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelBindingKey, exception, bindingContext.ModelMetadata);
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldHandleException(IInputFormatter formatter)
    {
        // Any explicit policy on the formatters overrides the default.
        var policy = (formatter as IInputFormatterExceptionPolicy)?.ExceptionPolicy ??
             InputFormatterExceptionPolicy.MalformedInputExceptions;
        return policy == InputFormatterExceptionPolicy.AllExceptions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting route like below and register startup use endpoints to map controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{resource}")]
[ApiController]
public class ResourceController : ControllerBase
{ 
   
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<IActionResult> Create([FromRoute] string resource, [FromBody] object model)
    {
          if(!ModelState.IsValid)
              return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Startup

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers(); 
        });
```

Comment: What would be the actual type of model in your example? I already have such a setup.

Comment: hmm that would be always json object. since you got resource I thought you would be able to convert to object and run validation using `.ToObject<resourceclass>();
.TryValidateModel`

Comment: I get your point. I just want to do that outside the action method. I would like to do it in the binder code, so I try now to implement my own binder

Comment: Actualy I would like it to be formatter unaware. The data might not always come in JSON format. Any formatter should read the input, I just want to provide to the formatting context the final data type I actually want

Comment: I am sure model bind would be able to do check and log validation errors. when it comes to api endpoints you are not worried about what type of object it is for further business process?

Comment: I found the solution. It was simple, but I could not find it online. I will post it as an answer

Comment: great! waiting for your answer